Is there a tree structure for QT widgets which allows us to access them by relative relationship?
I am developing an application using PyQt, please see attached image.
Besides the input field in the first row, I will generate more than 100 rows dynamically, each one having a large button (A1,A2,A3 ... A100, A101...) and a + and - button.
I don't want to name every plus and minus button with a unique name and bind each one individually.   If one of them is clicked I would like to get the corresponding row by accessing the Ax button as a sibling.
Is it possible??
This is done very easily in web applications, where you have a DOM.
I would assign a class with the same name, plus_button, to every + button, bind and action to the class and then by relative relationship I would access the corresponding Ax button which is a sibling of the clicked button.
Is it possibile in QT programs?
I think my question resolves to:
Is there a tree structure for QT widgets which allows us to access them by relative relationship?


If you're using a QGridLayout then use https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgridlayout.html#itemAtPosition - otherwise put your widgets into a struct / container to access them by index.

From the screenshot, it looks like each row is a QFrame with a QHBoxLayout holding the buttons. If so, the parent of each button will be its containing frame, so something like this should work: button.parent().layout().itemAt(0).widget(). Alternatively, you could try button.parent().children()[0] (assuming the buttons were added to the parent in the expected order). In Qt, the primitive functions of a DOM are  provided by QObject, QLayout and the Meta-Object System.

Many thanks, from your answers I understand there is something like a DOM, hence a tree structure. I weren’t able after doing some search to find something about it.

Note that since those rows are identical, a better solution would be to create a QWidget subclass that contains all the widgets in its row. This would make access to and from those widgets much easier.
